# How to integrate Skype for business functionality in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, skype-for-business

i have a requirement from my client that we need to add an option like Skype for business, and this conferencing info is sent automatically if they have a static url for conferences or phone information.  The end user could always update meeting with Skype for business info.

i am quite new to sdks Microsoft offers for this, Can anyone suggest example code samples to achieve it

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can start with looking at [Skype for business Web SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/skypewebsdk). The web SDK is will enable user to do IM, Audio, Video.

Before starting, please have a look into supported server versions and the features which are available in production. Refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/apiproductkeys) link.

Answer (score 0):

[Skype Web SDK](https://www.thoughtstuff.co.uk/skype-web-sdk/)

[Skype For Business](https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk#)

Answer (score 0):

1. Buy Office 365 Yearly Subscription , Create an Account for you 
   Link : https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-business-premium
2. Setup your Domain and Users 
   Link:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-domain-and-users-to-Office-365-6383f56d-3d09-4dcb-9b41-b5f5a5efd611?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US
   3.Install Skype in your Device , login with mentioned credentials and can chat with other users

Ref Link : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-Skype-for-Business-Online-40296968-e779-4259-980b-c2de1c044c6e